# Getting nullPointerException because Mockito variable is set to null even though I have mocked it

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

Here is the class and the method I am trying to unit test.

```
public abstract class ShowService {

    @Resource(name = "blogCoreSolrClient")
    private SolrClient blogCoreSolrClient;


    protected Show findShow(ClientRegion clientRegion, TargetLocale locale, Integer showId) {

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("type:" + SolrType.show)
                .addFilterQuery(getRegionQuery(clientRegion))
                .addFilterQuery(getLanguageFallbackQuery(locale))
                .addFilterQuery("show_id:" + showId)
                .setRows(1);

        QueryResponse response = blogCoreSolrClient.query(query);

        List<Show> shows = response.getBeans(Show.class);

        if (shows != null && shows.size() > 0) {
            return shows.get(0);
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static class SyndicatedShow {
        @Field("show_id")
        public Integer showId;

        @Field("path_value")
        public String pathValue;
    }
}
```

Here's my Unit test written using Mockito

```
public class ShowServiceTest {

    public final QueryResponse queryResponse = Mockito.mock(QueryResponse.class);
    public final SolrClient blogCoreSolrClient = Mockito.mock(SolrClient.class);
    public final SolrQuery SolrQuery = Mockito.mock(SolrQuery.class);
    private SolrDocumentList solrDocuments = Mockito.mock(SolrDocumentList.class);
    private ShowService showService = Mockito.mock(ShowService.class);


    @Test
    public void findShowTest() {
      Mockito.when(blogCoreSolrClient.query(solrQueryCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(queryResponse);
        
       

        Mockito.when(queryResponse.getResults()).thenReturn(solrDocuments);


       Mockito.when(blogCoreSolrClient.query(any())).thenReturn(queryResponse);

        ShowService.Show showsResult = ShowService.findShow(ClientRegion.US, TargetLocale.EN_US, 1234);

        assertThat(showsResult.pathValue).isEqualTo("shows/test/");
    }


}
```

I am getting Null at `blogCoreSolrClient` when the code passes to findShow().
Because of that I am getting NullPointerException.
Any suggestions, where I might be going wrong. TIA

Comment: Have you tried inserting actual values you would like to see in thenReturn(setSomeValueToReturn) part of the statements rather than the mocked instances themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems :

- You're mocking the class under test

```java
 private ShowService showService = Mockito.mock(ShowService.class);
```

- You don't tell to your ShowService to use the blogCoreSolrClient mock, then the blogCoreSolrClient mock instance is created, but never used.

As you are using IOC to inject the SolrClient (@Resource annotation), you need to inject the mock in your ShowService instance during the test.
There are different solutions, but the more convenient in your case would be to use the Mockito Extension to perform the injection.
Something like :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ShowServiceTest {

@Mock
private SolrClient blogCoreSolrClient;
... // Other mocks

@InjectMocks
private ShowService showService;

@Test
public void findShowTest() {
  Mockito.when(blogCoreSolrClient.query(any())).thenReturn(queryResponse);
  ... // Complete test

}

}
```

The problem would be that your class under test is an abstract class.
I don't see any abstract method. So, if you really need the class under test to be abstract, then you'll face a technical difficulty with @InjectMocks.
Here are some solutions :
https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2020/06/22/mockito-cannot-instantiate-injectmocks-field-the-type-is-an-abstract-class/

Comment: this doesn't seems to work in my case. I'm still getting the same error. Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: Could you please share what you have done? If you want to inject a mock in your class under test, you need to tell somewhere to your class under test to use the mock. To do this, the solutions are either injectmocks, constructor or setter.